# Get a filtered list from two lists

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, linq, listbox

I have a listbox where all my factories are loaded into. I also have a selected factories in listbox(1).

Binding Code for all factories in listbox right.

```
protected void fillWerke()
{
    //BindingListPersistable<Liebherr.Hau.Erp.Client> bl = new BindingListPersistable<Liebherr.Hau.Erp.Client>();
    AllFactory = new BindingListPersistable<Liebherr.Hau.Erp.Client>();
    AllFactory = Manager.LoadClients();
    BetroffeneWerkeAll.DataSource = from allF in AllFactory select allF.ClientCode;
    BetroffeneWerkeAll.DataBind();
}
```

What I tried is,

```
protected void fillWerke()
{
    //BindingListPersistable<Liebherr.Hau.Erp.Client> bl = new BindingListPersistable<Liebherr.Hau.Erp.Client>();
    AllFactory = new BindingListPersistable<Liebherr.Hau.Erp.Client>();
    AllFactory = Manager.LoadClients();
    var selectedFac;
    var filteredFac;
    if(SelectedWerke.Items.Count > 0)
    {
        selectedFac = SelectedWerke.Items;
        filteredFac = AllFactory.Except(selectedFac);
    }
    BetroffeneWerkeAll.DataSource = from allF in AllFactory select allF.ClientCode;
    BetroffeneWerkeAll.DataBind();
}
```

however, i hope u know what i mean, sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try instead of:

```
BetroffeneWerkeAll.DataSource = from allF in AllFactory select allF.ClientCode;
```

This:

```
 BetroffeneWerkeAll.DataSource = from allF in filteredFac select allF.ClientCode;
```

When you perform `Except` it returns the "input list except items in second list" and not sets the first list.

---

Not sure but it seems to me that `selectedFac` is of the type of `ClientCode` and not of an item in `AllFactory`. If that is the case you should use:

```
var result = AllFactory.Where(item => 
        !selectedFac.Any(filteredValue => filteredValue == item.ClientCode)).ToList();
```

Comment: @didntCthatcoming - If my additional explanations also helped you to understand the problem and not only solve it please consider upvoting my answer

Comment: @didntCthatcoming - Happy to here :)